# Can't fix a conflict between CloudZoom v1.0.3 and the default Bootstrap v2.3.1 Carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cloud, zooming, jquery-migrate

Bootstrap carousel and cloud zoom work but only with the first image. Here is a demo displaying the problem… http://responsive.jquery-zen-cart.com/normandy/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_2_3_4&products_id=2

Although the link above or cloud zoom is for an updated version, I figured I could maybe get an idea.

The carousel works by either clicking on either one of the previous, next and/or pause symbols in addition to clicking on the thumbnails below.

Maybe trying to add the function to the click or perhaps binding the cloud zoom upon completion of the carousel.

Comment: I'm using cloud zoom v 1.0.3 with Bootstrap v2.3.1. I managed to add the cloud zoom to the carousel but there seems to be a conflict and I do not know how to address it. I'm following the documentation located here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel and here: http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom/api.

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Is there still an issue?